# ODATA search against a string collection field, searching for one or more values

Tags: azure-search, odata

[image]

I've this document called **entities**.
I would like to execute this query that contains "IN" to allow me to select a document based on whether one or more values are contained in a string list field:
[image: query]

Sample shown includes the value `'region:1094'` but it is possible we need to search against more than one value.

Using the code above, I get this error:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "",
>           "message": "Invalid expression: ')' or ',' expected at position 46 in 'entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t:t in
>   'region:1094') or entity_id eq 'region:1094')'.\r\nParameter name:
>   $filter"
>       } }

My version is 2016-09-01

Answer (score 2):

Going to take a punt based on the ODATA syntax operators listed at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search

This appears to suggest that `any()` and `all()` functions don't support arbitrary lambdas but only those of simple equality or with the `search.in()` function, which is probably not what you want.  If I'm right in guessing that you would like any document that contains the value 'region:1094' within the `Collection(Edm.String)` value for the `ancestors` field you will probably get the result you're looking for from something along the lines of the following:

```
entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t: t eq 'region:1094') or (entity_id eq 'region:1094'))
```

In plain English I would describe this search as *any document such that*:

- the `entity_type` value is `'store'`, and
- either

  - the `entity_id` value is `'region:1094'`, or
  - the value `'region:1094'` is contained in the list of values in the `ancestors` field

It's not clear why you have decided you **must** use the `in` operator (not even totally sure there *is* an `in` operator in ODATA actually).  Perhaps you can clarify that in your question?  Typically the `any()` or `all()` functions accept a lambda to be executed against all the elements of a list, and pass that value to the lambda (that's the `t:` bit in your query).  `in` would seem redundant in this context, right?  Unless you mean that `region:1024` is only **part** of the value you're searching for.  In which case you should try the functions `startswith(myField,'val')`, `endswith(myField,'val')` or `substringof(myField,'val')`.  Note that while these are all valid ODATA operators the doco above explicitly states that only simple equality operators are supported by the `all()` and `any()` functions.

**EDIT:** To extend the above search to cover two fields (assuming these are 'equals' matches and not partial matches) such as `'region:1094'` and `'store:361'` you can use something like the following:

```
entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t: search.in(t,'region:1094|store:361','|') ) or (entity_id eq 'region:1094'))
```

The `search.in()` function will return `true` if the value in the first parameter (the field) matches any of the values in the second parameter which should be comma-separated.  If supplied, the third parameter (in the above case, `|`) swaps a comma list item separator for whatever is supplied.  I prefer the pipe since it's less likely to appear as a value - I assume your values are user-generated in Sitecore.

Otherwise, swapping to the Lucene syntax will support the expressiveness of the query you are trying to form? [Try doco here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search)

Comment: The problem is the follow: if i would more value inside function any , it get an error.

Comment: The problem is the follow: if i would more value inside function any , it get an error. I would like something of this: entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t: t eq 'region:1094' , 'store:361' ) or (entity_id eq 'region:1094')).   I want entity that have ancestor that contains for example 
'region:1094' or 'store:361' .

Comment: @drcimux I have updated the answer to include a sample that will probably do what you're looking for.  Again, I refer you to the fact that only simple lambdas are supported in the `any()` function, so for anything more complicated than the above you'll need to use the more expressive, but dramatically different, Lucene syntax

Comment: I use version 2016-09-01 and if I use search.in i got this error :{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: An unknown function with name 'eq' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
}  . If i write only in doesnt work.

Comment: Can you post your actual query, or is it exactly as I wrote it above?

Comment: the query is like this "filter": "entity_type eq 'store' and (ancestors/any(t:t IN 'region:c','region:gg')) or (entity_id eq 'region:1094')). ", . The problem is if i use more element for IN operator

Comment: There is no `IN`. You need to use `search.in()` instead